# Prove that $n(1+n)^{\frac{1}{n}} < n+H_n$ for every $n \geq 2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

> For every positive integer $n$ set $H_n = \dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n}$. Prove that $n(1+n)^{\frac{1}{n}} < n+H_n$ for every $n \geq 2$.

**Attempt**

I will prove this result by induction. The base case holds since for $n = 2$ we have  $(1+2)^{\frac{1}{2}} < 2 + H_2 = 3.5$. Now assume that $k(1+k)^{\frac{1}{k}} < k+H_k$ holds for some $k$. We need to show that $(k+1)(2+k)^{\frac{1}{k+1}} < 1+k+H_{k+1}$. How do I show this? Also, is induction the best way to prove this?

Comment: I do not think induction would be a good idea as the 2 expressions you obtained do not look close to each other.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus It is $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ that approaches $e$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Notice that $$n+1 = \frac{2}{1}\frac{3}{2} \cdots \frac{n}{n-1}\frac{n+1}{n}   $$
Hence by AM-GM we get
$$ \left (n+1\right )^{\frac{1}{n}} < \frac{ \frac{2}{1}+\frac{3}{2}+ \cdots \frac{n}{n-1}+\frac{n+1}{n}     }{n} $$
But observe that 
$$\frac{ \frac{2}{1}+\frac{3}{2}+ \cdots \frac{n}{n-1}+\frac{n+1}{n}     }{n}= \frac{n + H_n}{n}.$$
And we are done.

Comment: Nice. Can you show $n(\sqrt[n]{n+1}-1)\leq \ln n$ ?

Comment: You might want to make that inequality sign a strict inequality, as in the question.

Comment: @Element118 thanks for catching that

Comment: @ReneSchipperus thanks, not right off the bat, I will think about it.

Comment: @Rene It fails at least for $n=1$.

Comment: Well I would be just as happy with $\ln (n+1)$ on the right.

Comment: @Rene It looks like $\log n\le n(\sqrt[n]{n+1}-1)\leq H_n$ and the difference of the first two terms approaches zero from above.

Comment: @Rene In fact simple Taylor expansion shows that $n(\sqrt[n]{n+1}-1)= \log(n)+\frac {\log^2 n} {2n}+O(\frac {\log^3 n}{n^2})$ and hence is eventually larger than any $\log(n+k)$.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks, thats actually quite interesting.

Comment: @Rene I missed a $\frac 1 n$ term in the expansion - it needs to be added.